# Batch File Failing to create txt file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I can't seem to figure this one out, it's a fairly simple script. My if statement isn't checking for the file existence and the else command isn't creating a file in the appdata directory.

reg.exe is working correctly, the key has is added.

Any guidance would be great.

```
@echo
IF EXIST "%APPDATA%\outlookclean.txt" (exit
) 
else 
( 
% reg.exe add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\OutlookTest
@echo Done > "%APPDATA%\outlookclean.text"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is very specific. The `else` and its preceding and succeeding parentheses must all be on the same physical line with spaces.

Applies to the parenthesis before `exit` too...

```
@echo
IF EXIST "%APPDATA%\outlookclean.txt" ( exit
) else ( 
 % reg.exe add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\OutlookTest
 @echo Done > "%APPDATA%\outlookclean.text"
)
```

Not sure why your `reg.exe` line starts `%` - that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the old **`help if`** would give you a strong indication what might be wrong with your code:

According to the therefound documentation, the `else` command **must** be on the same line as the `if` command, because batch is a terrible language, so your code should look like this:

```
@echo off REM did you want to turn the output off?
IF EXIST "%APPDATA%\outlookclean.txt" (exit
) else (
REM notice the else being between the parenthesis? yeah, batch is terrible
REM also whats the deal with the % at th start of the next line?
reg.exe add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\OutlookTest
@echo Done > "%APPDATA%\outlookclean.text"
)
```